# ¿Por qué usar optional implícitos en Swift?

Tags: swift

Bueno, leyendo [The Swift Programming Language - The Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html) me encontré con el tema de los `optionals`, algo que ya le voy tomando la mano, pero no del todo todavía.
La duda es la siguiente:

¿Por qué usar un `implicit optional` en lugar de una variable normal?

Si al fin y al cabo, voy a tener que tener cuidado para que esta variable no sea `nil` cuando la use con `!`.

> If an implicitly unwrapped optional is nil and you try to access its wrapped value, you’ll trigger a runtime error. The result is exactly the same as if you place an exclamation mark after a normal optional that does not contain a value.

Código de ejemplo:

```
let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
let forcedString: String = possibleString!
let assumedString: String! = "An implicitly unwrapped optional string."
let implicitString: String = assumedString
```

En este caso, si alguna variable es `nil` y hago el *unwrapping* (implícito o explícito) daría error, entonces... 
¿En qué me conviene usar el optional implícito?

Debo estar entendiendo mal, no me va tan bien con el inglés y hago lo que puedo para entender pero bueno.

Comment: La idea es similar a la de `Optional<T>` de Java: en lugar de obtener directamente un `NullPointerException` porque tu variable es `null`, puedes hacer una evaluación previa (que no será `x != null` o `x != nil`) antes de obtener el valor real del objeto.

Comment: offtopic creo que te lo veo hacer hoy varias veces, si quieres formatear un codigo no tiene porque ir linea por linea o cosas por el estilo usando `, simplemente selecciona el codigo y pulsa Ctrl + k, cuando lo estas editando, creo que es mas facil y puedes fijarte que en este case se ve diferente. Saludos

Comment: Ah mira, no sabía. De ahora en más lo hago 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Son muy útiles a la vez que importantes. En tus ejemplos, hay alguno erróneo.

```
let possibleString: String? = "An optional string."
```

Esto no tiene sentido, ya que si le asignas un valor al declarar la variable, ésta ya no es `Optional`. Es decir, una forma correcta sería:

```
let possibleString = "An optional string."
```

(recuerda que los tipos se infieren, y hay que intentar evitar explicitarlos si es posible)

Para ejemplificar la importancia/utilidad de los `Optionals` fíjate en el siguiente caso. Imagina que tienes un manager para descargar contactos como la que sigue:

```
class ContactsManager: NSObject {

    // MARK: - Remote
    class func downloadLastContacts(date: NSDate, completion:(results: NSArray?, error: NSError?) -> ()) {

        // Código de descarga de los contactos

    }

}
```

Bien, por otro lado, tienes un `UIViewController` donde quieres mostrar esos contactos. Al instanciarlo, descargas los nuevos contactos a partir de una fecha dada. El código sería:

```
class ContactsViewController: UIViewController {

    var contacts: NSArray?
    var currentDate: NSDate

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle?) {

        // Asignamos fecha actual en el init
        // y por tanto NO es optional
        self.currentDate = NSDate()

        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        downloadContacts()

    }

    func downloadContacts() {

        // Descargamos "contacts" utilizando una fecha que NO es optional
        // y por tanto no hace falta hacer unwrapping
        ContactsManager.downloadLastContacts(currentDate) { (results, error) -> () in

            // Si contacts sigue siendo nil
            // mostramos la pantalla de "No hay contactos"
            // Para verificarlo, hacemos lo siguiente
            if let r = results {

                // Hay resultadmos, los guardamos
                self.contacts = r

            } else {

                // No hay resultados, mostramos
                // pantalla de "No hay contactos"
                // o un error en caso necesario

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Bien, si te fijas tengo dos propiedades, una `Optional` y la otra no. En el caso de la fecha, la inicializamos en el `init` y por tanto siempre tendrá un valor. También podemos inicializarla directamente tal que así, pero es cuestión de preferencias:

```
var currentDate = NSDate()
```

Por otro lado, tenemos la propiedad `contacts` que es `Optional`. Esto nos permite asegurarnos que hay contactos para mostrar. Al entrar en `UIViewController` llamamos a la función de descarga de contactos, si esta función no encuentra ningún contacto en el servidor, me devuelve un `Optional` y por tanto puedo actuar en consecuencia (en este caso muestro un mensaje o un error). Si devolviera algún resultado, lo guardaría en la variable `contacts` y la utilizaría más adelante.

A partir de aquí, se trata de ir jugando con los `if let` o los `guard else` para asegurar que hay o no algún valor y evitar errores en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el código por el siguiente y ejecutalo

```
let possibleString: String?
let forcedString: String = possibleString!
```

Ahora verás de lo que está hablando *The Swift Programming Language - The Basics*